# Tridion in the cloud - resources

Tags: cloud, tridion

I'm trying to find any information and best practices for implementing a Tridion 2011 in a cloud based infrastructure.  Has anyone any recent experience in doing this or are there any white papers from SDL which are worth visiting? It seems to be thin on the ground.

Thanks

Comment: What you are looking to put in the cloud? The Content Manager itself? Or just the Content Delivery part? And what type of technology stack?

Comment: Everything, from Content Manager through to the actual application.  SQL Server/MS .NET 4.0 MVC+DD4T most likely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have seen people use the Amazon Cloud Large instances to install the CMS Server + DB + FrontEnd on it for training purposes.

Things to consider:  (these are general best practices)

- Your Tridion CMS system is only as fast as your DB.  Keep the DB connection close and the DB server with plenty of CPU / Memory resources.
- The publisher consumes the most CPU.  It also communicates a lot to the DB.  Make sure it has enough RAM / CPU.  Consider running it on a separate box than the CMS.

You will probably run Large instances on Amazon EC2 to start with.  Since you'll need SQL Server (Or Oracle) to run the DB and also much RAM to support Windows and SQL Server you'll be running with at least large EC2 instances all the time.  You won't be able to benefit from the cheaper low resource instances that other software might be able to use.  At least for Dev and Test instances you could keep them powered on during the day and not at night to save costs.  You could also create AMI images for your Dev/Test systems to quickly spin up new ones for testing.

Comment: Thanks for this it validates my thoughts. I really think it would be valuable if SDL would provide some information on these potential scenarios with metrics which show where cost/benefit is at its most optimal.